# How can I override React Bootstrap css?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I can't figure out how I can override React Bootstrap css without using inline styles?  For example, I'm rendering an Alert

[image]

I made some css changes, but they are not getting applied since they are lower in priority.

In this example, you can see that I'm trying to override the padding:
[image]

I don't want to have to use inline styles  And I don't think `!important` is the way to go.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can refer to this documentation and changing some of the global css styles from bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/webpack/ or you can just use !important if you dont want this change to happen across your entire application

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class, add the appropriate css, and assign this class instead?

Comment: the thing is that using your own class wont override the styles unless you use !important. adding new styles is fine but changing others, bootstrap will override yours, unless im mistaken

Comment: Correct, but you can omit the BS styles from your class and substitute with your own. You will need to use a unique non-BS class name though.

For example: <div class = "new-alert"> instead of <div class ="alert">

Comment: Yes, creating a new class is possible.  I was hoping Bootstrap provided a more elegant way of doing it

Comment: If you didnt want to create a new class, and wanted something more 'elegant' then you can always go with SCSS and set a variable SCSS file? Generally this is more work to initially set up, but is a good way of creating a 'wrapper' over bootstraps defaults.